# Dark to light colours based on value ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, longitudinal

I am trying to customize the colours using ggplot2. The function I wrote is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
spaghetti_plot_multiple <- function(input, MV, item_level){
  MV <- enquo(MV)
  titles <- enquo(item_level)
  input %>% 
    filter(!!(MV) == item_level) %>% 
    mutate(first_answer = first_answer) %>%
    ggplot(.,aes( x = time, y = jitter(Answer), group = ID)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = first_answer)) +
    labs(title = titles ,x = 'Time', y = 'Answer', colour = 'Answer given at time 0') +
    facet_wrap(~ ID, scales = "free_x")+ 
    theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue', 'brown', 'purple', 'black'))
}
```

This however doesn't work, but I can't seem to figure out why `scale_color_manual(..)` values doesn't work. The current plot I am using is:

[image]

This is somewhat in line with what I am trying to achieve: a dark color for values 1-3 (i.e. based on `first_answer` which ranges from 1 to 5) and lighter ones for 4 and 5. The reason is simply because there are many more lines with a value of 4 or 5 and I want to be able to see the direction of lines across time.

**EDIT** The image is the plot I currently have. Although it somewhat resembles what I'd like to get, I'd much rather set the colors myself or use some function that chooses colors to enhance the plotting visibility (the lines in the plot) automatically.

Comment: have you tried `scale_color_gradient` or `scale_color_gradientn()` ?

Comment: Yes, adding `+ 
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("red","yellow","green","lightblue","darkblue"),
                           values=c(1.0,2,3,4,5,6)) ` doesn't do anything for me (just random colors as an example to try it out)

Comment: caveat the values need to be specified within the interval c(0,1), you have to map the range of your vector to this interval

Comment: Just tried: `theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 8))+ 
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("red","yellow","green","lightblue","darkblue"), 
                           values=c(1.0,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2,0))`. If I understand you correctly, this had to solve it. But it doesn't

Comment: The weird thing (or not) is just that it doesn't seem to take any custom values I assign. Whether it's through `scale_colour_gradientn()` or through `scale_colour_manual`, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: In this case, a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful to reproduce your problem. Have you tried the plot without the function? Does this give any result?

Comment: My bad, I must have done something wrong. I just retried your suggestions from scratch and it works. Thanks alot for your persistent help.

Comment: are you happy with the solution? may I then suggest this as an answer so that you can accept it?

Comment: Yes I am, go ahead and I will. Should you have some colour palette that works best at making the 5 lines distinct, feel free to suggest that in the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify color gradients with 'scale_x_gradient'  `scale_x_gradient2` or `scale_x_gradientn` 
(x can be `fill` or `color`)

Caveat when specifying the color values with `values = c(...)`): `values()` assigns colours based on their position within `c(0,1)`. You therefore need to scale the values from your vector which you want to have as breaks to the range c(0,1).

Re your question which palette best to use for 5 distinct lines: I think best is to manually specify the colours as you have done. I often use hex codes instead. I personally look those up at
[html color codes](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/).